# Connecting 3 different java files

Tags: java, string, object, arraylist

First it starts off with the class College tester, it askes the user for a command. 
The first command will be to add. what adding does is it askes the user to enter a name ( with at least 2 words by identifying a space) and an address.
Then it creates a student object with it. and I add the student object to a arraylist.

Issue #1: How would i add the collegetester input and create a student object out of it

Issue #2: after how would i add it to the array College

Collegetester (where i get user input)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollegeTester {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
    private String command;
    public String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CollegeTester collegeTester = new CollegeTester(); //creates object
        collegeTester.getCommand(); //goes to command
    }

    //Ask user for a command
    public void getCommand() {
        System.out.println("Enter a command: ");
        command = input.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("add"))
            addCommand(); //If command is add go to addcommand


    }

    //Add name and address to student object 
    public void addCommand() {
        String name = "";
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a Name: ");
            name = input.nextLine();
        } while (!(name.contains(Character.toString(' ')))); //To check if the name has at least 2 words
        System.out.println("Enter an Address: ");
        String address = input.nextLine();
        Student student = new Student(name, address);
        getCommand(); //repeat to see if user wishes to add another
    }


}
```

Student object (The student object)

```
public Student(String name, String address) {
    if (name == null)
        name = "";
    if (address == null)
        address = "";
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    lastAssignedNumber++;
    studentNum = lastAssignedNumber;

}
```

and the arraylist (In a different file)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class College {
    private ArrayList <College> entries = new ArrayList<College>();

}
```

Comment: Side note: `!(name.contains(Character.toString(' '))`... Why not just `!name.contains(" ")`?

Comment: If we tell you, you'll learn nothing.

Comment: becuase .contain only works string sequences or something i get errors

Comment: @Shimy Java String is a CharSequence, by the way...

Comment: i've been trying to connect the objects for the past week i just don't understand how objects work together.

Comment: @Ceiling gecko is there any advice or pages that you can reffer me to so i can understand connecting these objects (in different files)

Comment: Objects don't work together, what you need is a Student class with a constructor for the Student Object and then another class that create's a new Student Object and some methods that will insert new Students in the Object array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do a quick analysis of your code:

Your `Student` object looks like a constructor for the `Student` class object type which is most likely in this case an inner class of the CollegeTester class.

So here's the deal, your `addCommand()` already connects your CollegeTester class with your Student class, by executing this command after you provide the input for name and address it creates a new instance of the Student object.

This means that at this point, you need to add this newly created `Student` object to your `College` list.

However if you take a good look at your `College` list you will see that:

1. It's marked private (meaning it can be accessed only from within itself)
2. It is a list of `College` type objects (but you need a list of `Student` type objects)

So your options at this point are:

1. Make the list public
2. Create a public setter method that will do the adding

You will also need to change the list object type to `Student` if you wish to store `Student` objects in the list.

Also unless you want to have multiple colleges you might consider declaring your list as `static` otherwise you will have to declare an instance of it to add the `Student` objects to it.

Hopefully this is enough information to get you started in the right direction.

Also an advice is to not look at classes as actual objects, instead look at them as blueprints that can be used to construct those real objects.

Comment: thankyou,I fully understand how to add the student object into the array, but what if the student object is in a separate file. How do i create an object using the information in the collegetester.

Comment: If the `Student` is in a separate class file, you can access it from the `CollegeTester` class by importing the `Student` class at the top of `CollegeTester` next to where you import the `Scanner`, and that's it, you can then reference and create Student objects inside `CollegeTester` just make sure to specify the fully qualified name of the `Student` class when you import it.

Answer (score 0):

The main method should call a constructor in the Object array class that create's the Object `CollegeTester ct`.

```
ct = new CollegeTester();
```

Then a method to insert new students, that calls the Student constructor in the student class to create a new student Object.

```
ct.insert("input1", "input2");
```

write an insert method that calls to create a new student and adds that object to `College`.

Constructor to add values to the new student object:

```
String studentName;
String studentAddress;

public Student(String name, String address) {
    studentName = name;
    studentAddress = address;
}
```

note: with `ArrayList` you could simply use the method `add` of ArrayList.